# Why are black lines faded in the output?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, anti-aliasing, outline

Here is the screenshot of my artboard in Illustrator:
[image]

And here is its export:
[image]

As you can see, the dash lines is faded even when I don't use gradient. Do you know why is that?

Comment: Hi! To me, I don't actually see it as fading as much as aliasing artifacts. Could you maybe try to export it in different resolutions, tweak some quality settings a bit and see if the problem persists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wider strokes. Try also to avoid nearly horizontal and nearly vertical lines. If they are very narrow, they should be exactly horizontal or vertical to avoid severe anti-alias smoothing, which makes one pixel or less wide lines partially transparent.

Illustrator seems to be able to show narrow strokes as wider than they actually are to retain solid colors on the screen. But your target system hasn't that ability.

Comment: Actually it seemsto be just because you can not use the opengl preview as a rasterizer option for output.

Comment: @joojaa except a screenshot.

Comment: Otch. :D Thats fine if all you want is images smaller than your screen :)

Comment: we can increase the lines to 1.2 px for a quick fix. I wonder why is it limited to 1 px?